# Daily (open source) Bible devotional guide software

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any apps for my daily devotions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Xiphos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Xiphos) [image: Install Xiphos] or [gnome-sword](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-sword) [image: Install gnome-sword] (this is for older installations) for a complete solution, including the option to install daily devotionals (*though nothing beats reading the Bible as the Spirit leads in a free way ;)*).

P.S. they are the same program, but Xiphos is the renamed newer version.

There is also [bibletime](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bibletime) [image: Install bibletime] if you use QT/KDE or just want variety.

If you want to install extra Bible translations, Bible maps, and devotions, then add the crosswire.org sources within the program, and download as many as you want ;).

Hope that helps ^^!

Answer (score 3):

Open Synaptic **System → Administration  → Synaptic Package Manager** or the Software Center and search for "bible". There are quite a few bible programs to find there.

It seams like verse is the only dispositional. To install it either search for it in one of the above or just run this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install verse
```